# How do you organize the file system for a program that forks and execs?

Tags: c, file, exec, fork, program-entry-point

i'm working on a C project where the goal is to sort a file using multiple processes. The file is given to the first program, the 'root' process, but then root forks and execs to a 'splitter' process who then forks and execs to a 'sorting' process. basically a binary tree of processes that is used to sort.

my question is how do i organize all these programs in the file system. i am going to need 3 main methods correct? because when you exec the main method is run right? if so all 3 programs can't be in the same folder and compiled together right? i will have to have 3 different make files?

will i need something like this:
home folder

root folder -- splitter folder -- sorter folder

this is the first os project i've had that involves multiple processes.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single executable, which, after each call to fork(), can tell if it is the parent or child, and execute the appropriate code.

Comment: yes ok so if the process is a child it execs. then the process will have to start at its main right? or no?

Comment: @Tim - are you required to `exec` the children?  You should be able to do this in one program that just `fork`s its necessary children that, in turn, perform their functions.  In this way, no, the new programs do not start at main.

Comment: yes the children will be execd. i don't understand what happens after the exec though. will the children's main then be executed?

Comment: Yes. the exec-ed program's main will be run.  But then you are really writing three separate programs - main, spitter, and sorter.

Comment: ok thank you. so in regards to my first post, they can NOT all be compiled in the same folder right?

Comment: I don't use IDEs enough to know but I would think in most cases it is easier to set up each separately.  Presumably your IDE has some way to attach them all into one overall project.

Comment: They can be compiled in the same folder.  You will need 3 distinct executables, so each will need its own name and compiled (and linked) separately, even though each will have its own main().  They can each be created with the same makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can still have three executable files in the same folder, all compiled with the same makefile. Just name them differently.

Example Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS =

TARGET1 = program1
TARGET2 = program2
TARGET3 = program3
ALL_TARGETS = $(TARGET1) $(TARGET2) $(TARGET3)

all: $(ALL_TARGETS)

$(TARGET1): program1.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(TARGET2): program2.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(TARGET3): program3.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```